# How can I have my variable output enclose with a semicolon

Tags: powershell

Any idea how can I have my variable output enclose in a semicolon?

For example:

```
$animal = "cat"
```

My desire output of $animal is "cat" together with the semicolon. Anything I can do?

I tried parsing the semicolon to the output using ' but it will have spaces around it. For example if I do

write-host '"'$animal'"'

output would be " cat " with the space around it. I wanted it to be exactly "cat"

Thanks

Comment: Trim the space around it.

Comment: just for let you know: `;` this is a `semicolon`. `"` this is a `double quote`. `'` this is a `single quote`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try enclose it in single quote:

```
$animal = '"cat"'
```

or if you want only use `write-host` escape double quotes with `

```
$animal = "cat"

write-host "`"$animal`""
```

Comment: Hi C.B, write-host '"'$animal'"' would output " cat ", with the space, I wanted it to be "cat".

Comment: Hi C.B. cutting and paste your code works for both method, I must have have misread your code. Thanks a million! Wish you can realise your pipe dream to be a Natinal Geographic Photographer :)